# How to use a jar file with shared object in another java project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have some C files which I wanted to use in my java-android project. Used JNI wrappers and NDK to create SO. I was able to access the C methods from my java code. Everything works fine.
Now I want to create a jar file of this project, for providing it further to other developers(So that the C code can be hidden from others).
This is where I am facing some issues. When I am trying to use the created JAR in some other project I start getting the "UnsatisfiedLink Error" while loading the SO.
The SO is loading perfectly fine in the same project, however when creating the jar with same project and trying to use it in another project, it is causing issues.
*Using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When using eclipse/ant, you need to distribute your .jar and your .so files separately. Other developers will have to reintegrate the .so files themselves inside their `lib/ABI` folders.

You may find some hacky ways to get .so files integrated using additional jar files containing only the .so files, but that doesn't change the fact that you need to distribute them separately.

To distribute your library with its .so files as a single file, you should build an [**.aar**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) instead of a **.jar**. Android Studio/gradle can directly consume these, with *.so* files integrated directly under the `jni/ABI` folders of the aar file.